# can submit a form many time with the same csrf token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, csrf-protection

In my application, I have a form for creating a City.

Everything works fine when the remote option on the form is set to *false*. However, there is a problem when I change it to *true*.

When the form is submitted remotely, I can submit two forms with the same CSRF token and instead of getting the *ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken* error for the second request. The second requests would also create an object, which must not happen.

**Do you know what causes this problem and how can I fix it?**

```
<%= form_for [:administrators,@city],remote: true,:authenticity_token => true do |f| %>
<div class="field">

    <%= f.label :province_id,'Select a province' %>
    <%= f.select :province_id,options_from_collection_for_select(Province.all, :id,:name, @city.province_id),{ :prompt => 'Select province' } %> <br>
    <div class="errors alert-box alert" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name%> 
    <div class="errors alert-box alert" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="action">
    <% if @city.id? %>
        <%= f.submit 'Update', class:'button' %>
        <btn class='cancel_form_button button tiny alert'>  </btn>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.submit 'Create', class:'button' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Requests do come from your code and they __are__ authentic. So the token delivers on its promise. It doesn't promise to protect you from repeated requests, does it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you set the remote to false, and then try to submit a form for the second time, you will get the  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error

Comment: How do you submit the form the second time, if the page reloads?

Comment: Also, did you inspect the generated form? is the token hidden field there in the remote form?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev using FireFox developer tool you can edit and resubmit a request. yes the token in included.

Answer (score 0):

Do I get it correct that you want to prevent creation of `city` with the same params?

Then it's not CSRF token responsibility. CSRF prevents requests from other domains to your server, it's security feature.

Data validation (allowing only one city with some specific params) is a model validation responsibility. So you'll need to add `validates_uniqueness_of :name` to your `City` model. (also you may want to add `scope: :province_id` option). See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

On the other hand if you just want to prevent user from occasional double click on submit, you can add `disable_with` option to btn helper to disable it after click (you'll need to enable it back with your code after response)

Comment: no that is not what I meant. I think you should not be able to submit two forms with a same CSRF token, which it is possible in this situation but not possible when the form is not submitted remotely.

Comment: what happens when you submit form synchronously?

Comment: When I submit the form synchronously, if I try to submit a form for the second time with the same token I would get the InvalidAuthenticityToken error